# upgrade pip on mac to install a Django library?

Tags: python, django, macos, ssl, upgrade

I am working on a python/ django project from a mac, and have recently decided to switch to a different library for date/ time input on some of the forms on my website.

The library I have decided to change to is Bootstrap3, and I am following the instructions at: https://github.com/nkunihiko/django-bootstrap3-datetimepicker to install it.

The guide says that the first step is to 'Run `pip install django-bootstrap3-datetimepicker`', which I have done- and the bash console has displayed the message:

> Successfully built django-bootstrap3-datetimepicker
>
> Successfully installed django-bootstrap3-datetimepicker-2.2.3

However, it then displayed a message stating:

> InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this...

It also displayed another message stating:

> You are using pip version 8.1.2, however version 9.0.1 is available.
>
> You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command

I am quite new to Python/ Django, and have decided to change the library being used for the `datetimepicker` on the forms because of an issue with the current one that I haven't been able to resolve (it's not possible to select a date beyond the 01/01/2017 using the `datetimepicker` currently integrated into the project).

I am worried that if I upgrade Python on my computer, I might break another part of the project that is currently working correctly... is there a way to safeguard against this?

Should I upgrade pip before upgrading Python as the console suggests? What are the risks of doing this? Are there risks of breaking any of the existing code within my project when I upgrade Python too?

If I do go ahead and run these upgrades on the mac (my development machine), will I also need to run upgrades on the server, to ensure that the live website works correctly too?

Comment: You should *always* be using virtualenv.

Comment: A virtual environment? For what, the development of the Django/ Python project? How should I be using it? I am currently developing on my local machine, and pushing changes to the server using `Git` as and when I have fixed bugs/ added features, etc.

Comment: Yes, use it for that.

Comment: Ok. worth knowing that that's something to consider. But I have only recently taken on this project, having just started with this company about a month ago, so I am picking up where the person I took over from left off- and am just using the environment they had set up... which doesn't include a virtual environment. Are you able to help with the questions I asked in my OP?

Answer (score 1):

Has datetimepicker updated and working correctly? You don't necessarily have to upgrade if they are working correctly. You can test your ssl connection.

Moving from python 2 to 3 will definitely break your application. But your pip version can be upgraded easily without any bugs using

> pip install --upgrade pip

command.

I agree that you should be using virtualenv, but that won't save your program from breaking while migrating to newer python versions.